# pullsubscription no longer working with oAuth

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Looks like there is hardly any activity on EWS here but maybe...
I am in the process of supporting Oauth in my EWS app but i'm stuck on getting events from a pullsubscription.

There's no issue for mailbox folders, only public folders.

The only change in the code is that the exchange service now has Oauthcredentials and impersonates an email address that has owner permissions on the public folder .
When using basic authentication the exchange service credentials are that of a "service account" email address and it does not use impersonation to get a pullsubscribtion on the public folder.

I'm not getting errors when setting the pullsubscription, and I can check that it has an ID, so it is there. However when I issue the getevents method (after adding some items to the folder) nothing fires.

this is the trace of the getevents (i made sure there were events in the folder)

```
 26-8-2022 17:56:31 : EwsRequestHttpHeaders --- <Trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2022-08-26 15:56:31Z">
 POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Accept: text/xml
 User-Agent: 
 ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015
    
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
 X-AnchorMailbox: publicfolderstore_bac380fe@domainname.onmicrosoft.com
    
 X-PublicFolderMailbox: publicfolderstore_bac380fe@domainname.onmicrosoft.com
    
 X-PreferServerAffinity: True
    
 Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkRPRTZVMFJHdnM0X3FHanBhbU9KTjM1VHVsdmNRWUtjNHlFVDk2YnhfQjgiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSIsImtpZCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSJ9.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.GeDfpt7ABAp5WpL9su265dV9UvilX6lxt5eCj7FWrBqGLhSNOL6fRfGGH-98nOKbqONmpEiXe0M61cOagKnrlNoyNgnvsC6bE1v6Nt_Uk44MPHfAs4MW1GDn9RtGbL9EEIDTZFg4qwrfRToOkyliFIcsfpXnXKmBiVSN0XFXtyHdvJpCjrb7Jj4o-qzGKKF1BREAVHrpIHBMz1r8u3UVihMQBEnI8X-a_qOF7MmgeyKBCLabZ5oFXOVsVPCI9re89W0q9jx04d0gnBLSAsjSHh94aG0P7ffpjupu3GSpZAm6Y9AkWv629EDO_C1wOshdI8--F9yyqhJ44Oh90Ha9xw
    
    
 </Trace>
    
 26-8-2022 17:56:31 : EwsRequest --- <Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="1" Time="2022-08-26 15:56:31Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soap:Header>
       <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
       <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
         <t:ConnectingSID>
           <t:SmtpAddress>account@domainname.com</t:SmtpAddress>
         </t:ConnectingSID>
       </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
     </soap:Header>
     <soap:Body>
       <m:GetEvents>
         <m:SubscriptionId>JwBhczhwcjA3bWI3OTI1LmV1cnByZDA3LnByb2Qub3V0bG9vay5jb20QAAAAS114Ai9w+UayiTSZLtc6DY6SxEJ7h9oIEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=</m:SubscriptionId>
         <m:Watermark>AQAAABTg+YC4KZFNttW01ElEHaecAgsrAAAAAAA=</m:Watermark>
       </m:GetEvents>
     </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>
 </Trace>
    
 26-8-2022 17:56:31 : EwsResponseHttpHeaders --- <Trace Tag="EwsResponseHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2022-08-26 15:56:31Z">
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 request-id: de8811fe-8069-c2ff-15a7-5ac62e39d3f5
 Alt-Svc: h3=":443",h3-29=":443"
 X-CalculatedFETarget: AM6PR01CU002.internal.outlook.com
 X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200,200
 X-CalculatedBETarget: AS8PR07MB7925.eurprd07.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
 X-RUM-Validated: 1
 x-ms-appId: fdea1aff-feaa-4d04-b795-55d873f2283b
 Restrict-Access-Confirm: 1
 x-EwsHandler: GetEvents
 X-BeSku: WCS6
 X-DiagInfo: AS8PR07MB7925
 X-BEServer: AS8PR07MB7925
 X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness: 1
 X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus: 200
 X-FEProxyInfo: AM0PR02CA0136.EURPRD02.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
 X-FEEFZInfo: AMS
 X-FEServer: AM6PR01CA0042,AM0PR02CA0136
 X-FirstHopCafeEFZ: AMS
 Cache-Control: private
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 Date: Fri, 26 Aug 2022 15:56:28 GMT
 Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=52d38d4eb5c14276b165655c6cd18691; path=/; secure
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    
    
 </Trace>
    
 26-8-2022 17:56:31 : EwsResponse --- <Trace Tag="EwsResponse" Tid="1" Time="2022-08-26 15:56:31Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <s:Header>
       <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="5588" MinorBuildNumber="3" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
     </s:Header>
     <s:Body>
       <m:GetEventsResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
         <m:ResponseMessages>
           <m:GetEventsResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
             <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
             <m:Notification>
               <t:SubscriptionId>JwBhczhwcjA3bWI3OTI1LmV1cnByZDA3LnByb2Qub3V0bG9vay5jb20QAAAAS114Ai9w+UayiTSZLtc6DY6SxEJ7h9oIEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=</t:SubscriptionId>
               <t:PreviousWatermark>AQAAABTg+YC4KZFNttW01ElEHaecAgsrAAAAAAA=</t:PreviousWatermark>
               <t:MoreEvents>false</t:MoreEvents>
               <t:StatusEvent>
                 <t:Watermark>AQAAABTg+YC4KZFNttW01ElEHaf4BQsrAAAAAAE=</t:Watermark>
               </t:StatusEvent>
             </m:Notification>
           </m:GetEventsResponseMessage>
         </m:ResponseMessages>
       </m:GetEventsResponse>
     </s:Body>
   </s:Envelope>
 </Trace>
```

What could be the issue? Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are there more the one Public Mailbox Folder doing the hosting, from what you describing it sounds like you create the subscription on the mailbox/cas that is hosting the hierarchy but the content is hosted on another public folder mailbox. A few thing to be aware of are

With Push and Pull notification they are hosted on a particular CAS server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getevents-operation

> The SubscriptionID of the request is confirmed to be a valid subscription that is hosted on the Client Access server. If it is not, the GetEvents call fails.

So the first thing that might be happening is that routing of the request if failing. One thing you might want to do is compare the headers

X-CalculatedFETarget: AM6PR01CU002.internal.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200,200
X-CalculatedBETarget:

From when you using Basic and it working to when you using the oAuth

> The SMTP address of the authenticated user for the request is compared to the SMTP address of the user who created the subscription. If they do not match, the GetEvents request fails.

This is the other reason I could see it failing when using the client credentials flow. Impersonation from a Service Principal vs a User Principal maybe happening different on the back-end (could be bug). Probably the way to confirm that is test it using a Delegate that has a Mailbox and EWS Impersonation rights and use ROPC (or ever auth code flow) and see if the same thing happens.

These later thing should give different errors however.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Glen.

I have one public folder mailbox with one public folder in it. (It's on office365 ofcourse.)

I am including the full trace of subscription and response at the bottom.

The subscription ID is the same in both the subscription as the getevents.
I am not getting an error that the subscription was not found. So I would think that the problem is not routing?

The headers are these for resp subscribing and polling:

```
CalculatedFETarget: AM6P193CU004.internal.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200,200
X-CalculatedBETarget: AS8PR07MB7925.eurprd07.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM

CalculatedFETarget: AS8PR04CU007.internal.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200,200
X-CalculatedBETarget: AS8PR07MB7925.eurprd07.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
```

The CalculatedFETarget is different. Is this the hiarchy? Do you think this could be an issue?

This *"Probably the way to confirm that is test it using a Delegate that has a Mailbox and EWS Impersonation rights and use ROPC (or ever auth code flow) and see if the same thing happens."* is over my head.
In the current code, the account that is impersonated by the oAuth authenticated ExchangeService has application impersonation permissions and is listed as owner of the public folder.

I would like to emphasize that everything works fine for mailbox folders. In that case the owner/email address of the mailbox is impersonated by the oAuth authenticated ExchangeService.

*"Impersonation from a Service Principal vs a User Principal maybe happening different on the back-end (could be bug)."*
It could indeed be a bug. Do you know how a single person like me can still get access to Microsoft for this. One used to be able to raise a (paid) incident but now  you need a prem. support contract to reach them.

```
==========  subscription  ==========
    
    
    1-9-2022 12:57:13 : EwsRequestHttpHeaders --- <Trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2022-09-01 10:57:13Z">
    POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Accept: text/xml
    User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    X-AnchorMailbox: publicfolderstore_bac380fe@MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com
    X-PublicFolderMailbox: publicfolderstore_bac380fe@MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com
    X-PreferServerAffinity: true
    Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6InA5eWx3dnE4RW9zQzJMdjNCeklmYzZxTlh1bjVmQzl3QXAyWENGbG1QOVkiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSIsImtpZCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSJ9.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.IlPfIOgl6H7Kenn999w6GPrHjPKyT_T_JLxSQc2w1Pjs8W_W4_brehe_wVX8YdqQPLEOo4fYX9l3gHHZeXtuOkgir1hM9w6TomM_FP6vBTeuGjVe7xLL0fSPvAd63pwvQicCj7SbX-RQBpvKeAapf5zA70UOYfo_NKic_ErJSWoYkSvDDX67LipjQrZ68X8XQQe3z_U7PfbwKABY91twQftzI4WXbQoRcEv8AgCQ9dxhFTIJgdzeV6slf-vnPHQ2Ic2bSnHpIJRGW-TV3o7zb6eRkTib1xs6SDBd3PIWAZoEz-uQbJ1MXwUEETfcDLNGkGYk25WqgI0tIGbqQoG_oQ
    
    
    </Trace>
    
    1-9-2022 12:57:13 : EwsRequest --- <Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="1" Time="2022-09-01 10:57:13Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Header>
          <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
          <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
            <t:ConnectingSID>
              <t:SmtpAddress>UserAccount@Domain.com</t:SmtpAddress>
            </t:ConnectingSID>
          </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
          <m:Subscribe>
            <m:PullSubscriptionRequest>
              <t:FolderIds>
                <t:FolderId Id="AQEuAAADTfhLNwPj+06PL1ijINAF1AEACMU9HL7QIUqU8ZZs9tXeAQAAAxYAAAA=" />
              </t:FolderIds>
              <t:EventTypes>
                <t:EventType>CreatedEvent</t:EventType>
                <t:EventType>CopiedEvent</t:EventType>
                <t:EventType>DeletedEvent</t:EventType>
                <t:EventType>ModifiedEvent</t:EventType>
                <t:EventType>MovedEvent</t:EventType>
              </t:EventTypes>
              <t:Timeout>90</t:Timeout>
            </m:PullSubscriptionRequest>
          </m:Subscribe>
        </soap:Body>
      </soap:Envelope>
    </Trace>
    
    1-9-2022 12:57:13 : EwsResponseHttpHeaders --- <Trace Tag="EwsResponseHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2022-09-01 10:57:13Z">
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    request-id: 020ba111-367c-5403-10d0-edb4d8408dc5
    X-CalculatedFETarget: AM6P193CU004.internal.outlook.com
    X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200,200
    X-CalculatedBETarget: AS8PR07MB7925.eurprd07.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
    X-RUM-Validated: 1
    x-ms-appId: fdea1aff-feaa-4d04-b795-55d873f2283b
    Restrict-Access-Confirm: 1
    x-EwsHandler: Subscribe
    X-BeSku: WCS6
    X-DiagInfo: AS8PR07MB7925
    X-BEServer: AS8PR07MB7925
    X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness: 1
    X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus: 200
    X-FEProxyInfo: AM3PR05CA0132.EURPRD05.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
    X-FEEFZInfo: AMS
    X-FEServer: AM6P193CA0116,AM3PR05CA0132
    X-FirstHopCafeEFZ: AMS
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2022 10:57:10 GMT
    Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=fae0cd80fcd944e9b2e3ac0e021b8dc8; path=/; secure
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    
    
    </Trace>
    
    1-9-2022 12:57:13 : EwsResponse --- <Trace Tag="EwsResponse" Tid="1" Time="2022-09-01 10:57:13Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Header>
          <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="5612" MinorBuildNumber="5" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body>
          <m:SubscribeResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
              <m:SubscribeResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                <m:SubscriptionId>JwBhczhwcjA3bWI3OTI1LmV1cnByZDA3LnByb2Qub3V0bG9vay5jb20QAAAAcX9pz2c1LEavlEM3OLE6OTYrWLgIjNoIEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=</m:SubscriptionId>
                <m:Watermark>AQAAABTg+YC4KZFNttW01ElEHadDSGwrAAAAAAA=</m:Watermark>
              </m:SubscribeResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
          </m:SubscribeResponse>
        </s:Body>
      </s:Envelope>
    </Trace>
    
    =============  get events ==============
    
    
    1-9-2022 13:00:23 : EwsRequestHttpHeaders --- <Trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2022-09-01 11:00:23Z">
    POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Accept: text/xml
    User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    X-AnchorMailbox: publicfolderstore_bac380fe@MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com
    X-PublicFolderMailbox: publicfolderstore_bac380fe@MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com
    X-PreferServerAffinity: True
    Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6InA5eWx3dnE4RW9zQzJMdjNCeklmYzZxTlh1bjVmQzl3QXAyWENGbG1QOVkiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSIsImtpZCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSJ9.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.IlPfIOgl6H7Kenn999w6GPrHjPKyT_T_JLxSQc2w1Pjs8W_W4_brehe_wVX8YdqQPLEOo4fYX9l3gHHZeXtuOkgir1hM9w6TomM_FP6vBTeuGjVe7xLL0fSPvAd63pwvQicCj7SbX-RQBpvKeAapf5zA70UOYfo_NKic_ErJSWoYkSvDDX67LipjQrZ68X8XQQe3z_U7PfbwKABY91twQftzI4WXbQoRcEv8AgCQ9dxhFTIJgdzeV6slf-vnPHQ2Ic2bSnHpIJRGW-TV3o7zb6eRkTib1xs6SDBd3PIWAZoEz-uQbJ1MXwUEETfcDLNGkGYk25WqgI0tIGbqQoG_oQ
    
    
    </Trace>
    
    1-9-2022 13:00:23 : EwsRequest --- <Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="1" Time="2022-09-01 11:00:23Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Header>
          <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
          <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
            <t:ConnectingSID>
              <t:SmtpAddress>UserAccount@Domain.com</t:SmtpAddress>
            </t:ConnectingSID>
          </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
          <m:GetEvents>
            <m:SubscriptionId>JwBhczhwcjA3bWI3OTI1LmV1cnByZDA3LnByb2Qub3V0bG9vay5jb20QAAAAcX9pz2c1LEavlEM3OLE6OTYrWLgIjNoIEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=</m:SubscriptionId>
            <m:Watermark>AQAAABTg+YC4KZFNttW01ElEHadDSGwrAAAAAAA=</m:Watermark>
          </m:GetEvents>
        </soap:Body>
      </soap:Envelope>
    </Trace>
    
    1-9-2022 13:00:23 : EwsResponseHttpHeaders --- <Trace Tag="EwsResponseHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2022-09-01 11:00:23Z">
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    request-id: 614cb84b-af3f-c278-0910-971429e39c7b
    X-CalculatedFETarget: AS8PR04CU007.internal.outlook.com
    X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200,200
    X-CalculatedBETarget: AS8PR07MB7925.eurprd07.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
    X-RUM-Validated: 1
    x-ms-appId: fdea1aff-feaa-4d04-b795-55d873f2283b
    Restrict-Access-Confirm: 1
    x-EwsHandler: GetEvents
    X-BeSku: WCS6
    X-DiagInfo: AS8PR07MB7925
    X-BEServer: AS8PR07MB7925
    X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness: 1
    X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus: 200
    X-FEProxyInfo: AM4P190CA0002.EURP190.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
    X-FEEFZInfo: AMS
    X-FEServer: AS8PR04CA0209,AM4P190CA0002
    X-FirstHopCafeEFZ: AMS
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2022 11:00:20 GMT
    Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=fae0cd80fcd944e9b2e3ac0e021b8dc8; path=/; secure
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    
    
    </Trace>
    
    1-9-2022 13:00:23 : EwsResponse --- <Trace Tag="EwsResponse" Tid="1" Time="2022-09-01 11:00:23Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Header>
          <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="5612" MinorBuildNumber="5" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body>
          <m:GetEventsResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
              <m:GetEventsResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                <m:Notification>
                  <t:SubscriptionId>JwBhczhwcjA3bWI3OTI1LmV1cnByZDA3LnByb2Qub3V0bG9vay5jb20QAAAAcX9pz2c1LEavlEM3OLE6OTYrWLgIjNoIEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=</t:SubscriptionId>
                  <t:PreviousWatermark>AQAAABTg+YC4KZFNttW01ElEHadDSGwrAAAAAAA=</t:PreviousWatermark>
                  <t:MoreEvents>false</t:MoreEvents>
                  <t:StatusEvent>
                    <t:Watermark>AQAAABTg+YC4KZFNttW01ElEHafKVmwrAAAAAAE=</t:Watermark>
                  </t:StatusEvent>
                </m:Notification>
              </m:GetEventsResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
          </m:GetEventsResponse>
        </s:Body>
      </s:Envelope>
    </Trace>
```

Comment: The subscription ID is the same in both the subscription as the getevents. I am not getting an error that the subscription was not found. So I would think that the problem is not routing? Yep that's the strangest thing to me, Public folders generally have replica's and there will be multiple instances spread across Dag's. This is where you really need someone at the Microsoft end to look at the logs to see what is happening based on the requestId you are submitting

Comment: Do you know how a single person like me can still get access to Microsoft for this. One used to be able to raise a (paid) incident but now you need a prem. support contract to reach them. I don't know on this on if you are a Microsoft Partner reach out via those channels otherwise everything is plan based now AFAIK. I would make sure you have a reproduceable sample code app (outside of what your doing now) and verify that the problem exists on a sperate tenant, that will save a lot of time in the support process.